# writing some numbers into csv like comparision matrix

Tags: python

I am using python to write some comparison value as below mentioned:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3] 
vals = [0.0, 0.71, 0.89, 0.71, 0.0, 0.77, 0.89, 0.77, 0.0]
```

where ids are id_number (int) of 3 chemical compounds derived from a database and vals are comparison values with each others ......but I want these ids and vals TO BE WRITTEN INTO A CSV FILE like below:

```
    1        2        3

1   0.0      0.71     0.89 

2   0.71     0.0      0.77

3   0.89     0.77     0.0
```

ONLY UPPER OR LOWER TRINGULAR MATRIX WRIITEN INTO CSV WILL BE BETTER

Comment: (1) What is your question? (2) The C in CSV is short for "comma". I see no commas in your output sample.

Comment: @JohnMachin: Well, yes, but other separators are legal in CSV files than just commas, tabs being one of them (OK, more often those are TSV files). But for example European Excel versions use semicolons, and they don't call them SSVs...

Answer (score 5):

Using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv):

```
import csv

ids= [1, 2, 3] 
vals = [0.0, 0.71, 0.89, 0.71, 0.0, 0.77, 0.89, 0.77, 0.0]

with open('/tmp/test.csv','w') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    writer.writerow(['']+ids)
    for i,row in enumerate(zip(*[iter(vals)]*3),1):
        writer.writerow((i,)+row[:i])
```

This creates a lower triangular matrix:

```
    1   2   3
1   0.0
2   0.71    0.0
3   0.89    0.77    0.0
```

The [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes), `zip(*[iter(vals)]*3)`, was used to group `vals` into 3-tuples.

Comment: A _much_ better answer than this question deserved :)